# Internal server error 500 when I am trying to get all `groupid` from `ektron` in .net (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, internal-server-error

My code:

```cs
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(domainUrl + "/Workarea/webservices/WebServiceAPI/User/User.asmx/GetAllUserGroups");
```

```cs
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "OrderBy=Id";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
getXmlValue1(responseString);
```

Comment: I see, you did not get a response in the meantime. Try to post more information. What did you try, what is the complete error message, or post more code.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the above piece of code at my end (Ektron V9),and it's working fine.

The issue may be with the ektron site that you are referring.

Check whether the Ektron website to which you make the POST request is accessible or not.